# Android ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, kotlin

until yesterday my app was working just fine, today suddenly it start to crashing with a Retrofit2 error so i solve it by upgrading the dependency and adding multidex to my app, the problem is that now when i try to start the app it does not find any activity class like it doesn't exist, i reviewed every similar question here and no answer solved my problem, i have no idea how to solve it now, any ideas?, i use a custom Application class:

MainApplication(Kotlin):

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MainApplication.appContext = applicationContext
    }

    companion object {
        var appContext: Context? = null
            private set
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.aarr.vip365">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

    <!--<permission-->
        <!--android:name="com.project.purifficapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"-->
        <!--android:protectionLevel="signature" />-->
    <!-- Allows to receive map -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.project.purifficapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Used by the Google Maps Android API V2 to download map tiles from Google Maps servers -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_circle" -->

    <application
        android:name="com.aarr.vip365.MainApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_quarevip"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        tools:node="replace">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.RegistroActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.PagosActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.BuscarRutaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.ConfiguracionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.aarr.vip365.Views.EditUserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aarr.vip365"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
//            multiDexKeepFile file 'multidex_config.txt'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    android.defaultConfig.manifestPlaceholders = [
            facebookAppId        : "516038112090677",
            googleWebClientId    : "215137711124-8bir20vatiima1fll9ehba0jv7ch9itb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            twitterConsumerKey   : "your twitter consumer key",
            twitterConsumerSecret: "your twitter consumer secret",
            instagramClientId    : "your instagram client id",
            instagramClientSecret: "your instagram client secret",
            instagramRedirectUri : "your instagram redirect uri"
    ]
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'

    compile 'com.github.championswimmer:Android-SocialButtons:1.0'
    compile 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.github.KingsMentor:Luhn:v2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.jaychang0917:SimpleAuth:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:

```
10-12 13:18:37.014 15090-15090/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aarr.vip365, PID: 15090
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.aarr.vip365/com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.aarr.vip365-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.aarr.vip365-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.aarr.vip365-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.aarr.vip365-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity
                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                               at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                               at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                    ... 14 more
                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aarr.vip365.Views.SplashActivity
                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)... 13 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'`

Comment: that would be to solve retrofit issue but that one i already solve it by upgrading it to last version, but still i try it and still same

Comment: Sounds like a mutlidexing issue. Have you tried cleaning?

Comment: yes, i already clean and rebuild many many times, even invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Are you using the latest gradle plugin?

Comment: i'm using gradle-3.3-all, i will download the last one

Comment: What is your `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version? I am 90% sure your problem lies with multidexing. It even looks like it is only dexing in to one apk... meaning it may not be large enough to split yet. So possibly try removing multidexing and see if it runs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156592/discussion-between-andres-rodriguez-and-chad-bingham).

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Instant Run on Android Studio worked for me. (Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run)